# CORS Headers issue in Ionic Browser Application

Tags: rest, http, ionic-framework, grails, cors

I have a REST API implemented in Grails using the rest-api profile. In the method findProfile I am returning the CORS headers required by Ionic to pass CORS checks. I have deployed the Application to Apache2 and the URL for the REST API is NOT going through the Ionic Proxy. Yesterday, my API Service did not return the CORS headers and that made things fail. I corrected the problem and it works if I test the Application with ionic serve and change the URLs to go through the proxy. But when I try to access the same function on the Apache2 deployed App I am not getting the CORS headers back, like something got cached. Very strange. Any idea why this could be happening?

A few more details:
The ionic app and the REST API are deployed on the same host.

I understand that CORS is only an issue if testing the application locally via ionic serve or ionic run. I also understand that Proxies are only applicable in the above mentioned situation.

I am calling other functions from the same REST API and those have no issues.

Please let me know what more information would you need me to share to help you understand the problem and get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the source of my problem.

For all requests that had a content-type other than application/json, a pre-flight request for CORS was not being issued, therefore no failures because the server gladly accepted the request.

On the other hand, when a request with a content-type of application/json was submitted, a pre-flight CORS request with method OPTIONS was sent to the server prior to the original POST request. Since my Grails REST API application was not CORS enabled, the pre-flight request was failing. It was not failing when going through a proxy because the pre-flight request is not generated when going through a proxy. That's why, when testing locally, it was working fine.

Just in case you're wondering how to enable CORS support in Grails 3.2.11. Here is how:

In the application.yml file, at the very top (not sure if that matters, probably not, but I added it at the top) add the following:

Right under the grails: tag (see below)

grails:
    cors:
        enabled: true

This makes it wide open but you can tight it up as you need. For more information see this link:

http://docs.grails.org/3.2.11/guide/single.html#whatsNewCors

Rebuilt my self-contained WAR, deployed it and voila. Works like a charm.

Hope this helps people having the same issues I had.